# Failing login to firebase account throws exception and stops flutter app

Tags: firebase, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter

I am implementing a email and password sign in form in my flutter app, but when I fail to login (e.g. badly formatted email or wrong password) the app throws platform exception and the simulator stops responding.

Here is my handle login function:

```
Future<FirebaseUser> _handleLogin(String email, String password) async {
    print(email);
    print(password);
    print(_firebaseUser);
    try {
      FirebaseUser user = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      print("done logging in");
      print(user.uid);
      setState(() {
        _firebaseUser = user;
      });
      print("new user set");
      return user;
    } catch (err) {
      print(err.toString());
      return null;
    }
}
```

Even when I use a wrong password, the error never gets printed to the console. Instead VS code opens up message_codecs.dart and gives me an error message.

This is the error message when I use a wrong password to login:

```
Exception has occurred.
PlatformException(Error 17009, FIRAuthErrorDomain, The password is invalid or the user does not have a password.)
```

Am I doing the error handling in a wrong way? How can I catch the error and make the app continue after wrong password or badly formatted email entered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using Visual Studio Code, then please uncheck the "Uncaught Exceptions" option. This would solve your problem. The statement inside the catch block will be executed.
[Please check the below image where both the options are unchecked.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctTKS.png)

Answer (score 4):

Use `finally` after it.

```
Future<FirebaseUser> _handleLogin(String email, String password) async {
    print(email);
    print(password);
    print(_firebaseUser);
    FirebaseUser user;
    try {
      user = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      print("done logging in");
      print(user.uid);

      print("new user set");
      return user;
    } catch (err) {
      print(err.toString());
    }
      finally {
       if(user != null) {
         //Log in was successfull! 
         setState(() {
          _firebaseUser = user;
        });

      }
      else {
         //Log in was unsuccessfull!
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Futures and error handling](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/futures-error-handling) in Dart. You can also use `.then` and `.onError` to handle the errors. I'm calling `SetState()` to show the error message on the screen. The example code below is for registering.

```
void _register() async {
  AuthResult result;

  await _auth
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: _emailController.text,
    password: _passwordController.text,
  )
      .then((value) {
    result = value;
  }, onError: (error) {
    _errorDesc = error.message;
    setState(() {
      _success = false;
    });
  });

  if (result != null) {
    setState(() {
      _success = true;
      _userEmail = result.user.email;
    });
  }
}
```